# What is the Rust equivalent of a TypeScript hashmap with optional typed values for specific keys?

Tags: rust

I want to be able to have a data structure that can have keys with specific types (like a Rust struct) but may have optional values that don't need to exist (like a `HashMap`). Is there a data type that is halfway between both? What's the best way to approach this?

I'm learning Rust, but use TypeScript on a daily basis. I know that the two type systems are different, I'm just trying to achieve something similar. In TypeScript, I can do:

```js
interface Example {
  value1: string;
  optional?: number;
  value3?: "hello" | "goodbye";
}
```

and when creating an object to match it:

```js
const obj: Example = {
  value1: "this works"
}
```

I'm exploring contributing to [DenisKolodin/yew](https://github.com/DenisKolodin/yew) and the first thing I wanted to try my hand at was a [free-style](https://github.com/blakeembrey/free-style) implementation in an idiomatic Rust way. Being able to declare styles in a struct with specific enum types ("flex", "block" etc) but not require each possible style/CSS selector is key to this kind of library.

Any and all examples are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the usecase for `HashMaps` in Rust. A `HashMap` has keys that are unknown at compile time, which is not what you want here. Structs have a fixed set of known keys, while enums have a fixed set of possibilities.

The direct translation of your code creates a struct and an enum, using `Option` to denote the optional fields:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Example {
    value1: String,
    optional: Option<i32>,
    value3: Option<Value3Values>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Value3Values {
    Hello,
    Goodbye,
}
```

While serviceable, this can be *annoying* to construct compared to what you are used to:

```
Example {
    value1: String::from("hello"),
    optional: None,
    value3: Some(Value3Values::Goodbye),
}
```

We can apply some steps to improve it. Using `Default` plus the *struct literal update syntax* makes all the default values easier:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Example { /* ... */ }
```

```
Example {
    value1: String::from("hello"),
    value3: Some(Value3Values::Goodbye),
    ..Example::default()
}
```

You can then also apply the `Into` / `From` traits to remove some of the conversion:

```
Example {
    value1: "hello".into(),
    value3: Value3Values::Goodbye.into(),
    ..Example::default()
}
```

And you can wrap it up in a macro to avoid the repetition:

```
macro_rules! thing {
    ($t:ident, { $( $name:ident : $val:expr ),*, }) => (
        $t {
            $( $name: Into::into($val) ),*,
            .. $t::default()
        }
    );
}

fn main() {
    thing!(Example, {
        value1: "hello",
    });

    thing!(Example, {
        value1: "hello",
        optional: 32,
    });

    thing!(Example, {
        value1: "hello",
        value3: Value3Values::Hello,
    });

    thing!(Example, {
        value1: "hello",
        optional: 32,
        value3: Value3Values::Hello,
    });
}
```

There are even ways to use string literals for `value3`, but I'd avoid it. "Stringly-typed" APIs are annoying.

```
macro_rules! value3 {
    ("hello") => (Value3Values::Hello);
    ("goodbye") => (Value3Values::Goodbye);
}

fn main() {
    thing!(Example, {
        value1: "hello",
        value3: value3!("hello"),
    });

    thing!(Example, {
        value1: "hello",
        optional: 32,
        value3: value3!("goodbye"),
    });
}
```

There may even be cleverer macro tricks to avoid needing to call the macro `value3!` inside `thing!`.

---

A *very* advanced technique would be to use a [*build script*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) to generate custom macros for every set of CSS attributes, perhaps using the [MDN CSS JSON DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Howto/Update_the_CSS_JSON_DB). You'd end up with something like:

```
macro_rules! example {
    ( $( $name:ident : $val:tt ),*, ) => (
        Example {
            $( $name: example!(field @ $name : $val) ),*,
            .. Example::default()
        }
    );

    // Internal details
    ( field @ value1 : $val:expr ) => (Into::into($val));
    ( field @ optional : $val:expr ) => (Into::into($val));
    ( field @ value3 : hello ) => (Some(Value3Values::Hello));
    ( field @ value3 : goodbye ) => (Some(Value3Values::Goodbye));
    ( field @ value3 : $val:expr ) => (
        compile_error!(r#"value3 can only be "hello" or "goodbye""#)
    );
}

fn main() {
    example! {
        value1: "name",
    };

    example! {
        optional: 42,
    };

    example! {
        value1: "name",
        value3: hello,
    };

    example! {
        value1: "name",
        optional: 42,
        value3: goodbye,
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the in-depth answer. The macro syntax is extremely foreign to me but I'll give it a look. That is much closer to what I wanted to do. I'll start down this path and see how it goes. It's very exciting, and the thought of not having to touch javascript again is extremely appealing :).

Comment: As an aside, free-style allows arbitrary CSS selector keys, i.e. `& >div::hover` etc. What do you think is the best way to approach that in a library like this for Rust?

Comment: @AlexanderMattoni I can't answer that because nowhere in this question are any selectors referenced, so I don't begin to have the context needed to provide anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript and JavaScript has two [nullable types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type): `null` and `undefined`.

Most other languages initially didn't, because it's not a clear-cut win to have the two option types (cf. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0&feature=youtu.be&t=9m21s from https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/null-undefined.html; https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#null-and-undefined).

In Rust you'd use the [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/error-handling.html#the-option-type) instead, which (most of the time) corresponds to both the `null` and `undefined` of JavaScript and TypeScript.

```
struct Example {
    value1: String,
    optional: Option<i64>,
    value3: Option<String>
}
```

P.S. In order to specify just the fields you want to specify, and leave all the other fields at `None`, you can tell the language to implement the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) for the struct:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Example {
    value1: String,
    optional: Option<i64>,
    value3: Option<String>
}

fn new_example() -> Example {
    Example {
        value1: "foobar".into(),
        ..Default::default()
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but when creating a struct that has those Option parameters, it complains when initiating a struct if you leave those optional fields out. If I'm creating a type to describe all possible CSS styles like `background-color`, it'd be impossible to use because you'd need to list each field you're not using as well (in which case there could be hundreds).

Comment: @AlexanderMattoni `Default` might help, I've added example of it to the answer.

Comment: I'm not a JS guy, but I don't think you're using the term "bottom" correctly. `null` is a value, not a type, right?